# Share NDB datastore across modules

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

App Engine modules allow you to create discrete code in different languages (Python, Java, Go, PHP) that share the same datastore.

I'm wondering whether there are plans for the PHP module to support the NDB datastore?

An existing python application with an NDB backend may want to share it's data with a PHP module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two misconceptions here:

1. Applications are totally separated, including having separate datastores. Modules however run inside an application and share the same datastore.
2. Python NDB is an API to the datastore: whether you use NDB or old Python API, datastore contents will be the same.

To answer your question: if Python NDB module is run on the same application as PHP module, then they will share the same datastore an see all data.

AFAIK, there are no plans to have access to datastore of an application from another application.

Comment: A PHP model-layer would have to use the same memcache keys to operate properly alongside NDB.

Comment: @Greg - you are right. In this case it would be best to turn caching off: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#policy_functions